# Download last N items from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I wanted to download last N items from an S3 bucket and I thought I should use `--page-size`.

From [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

> --page-size (integer) The number of results to return in each response to a list operation. The default value is 1000 (the maximum allowed). Using a lower value may help if an operation times out.

And here, there is my command when I try to get 15 items:

```bash
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/mydirectory . --page-size 15
```

**However, I retrieve all the items.**

Am I wrong using `--page-size`?

How can I get those last N items?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`--page-size` refers to the number of items to request from S3 in each list objects request sent to the S3 API... but aws-cli will keep sending requests for more objects until S3 reports that the end of the list has been reached.

This option is probably only useful in the case of weird network issues where you need each set of items returned to be small.  It increases cost because more requests are sent, and slows down the process because more round trips are required, but has no impact on the actual work that `aws s3 sync` will ultimately do.

Also, object listings have no concept of "last" -- the objects are always sorted lexically, from lowest to highest (i.e., ASCII 0-9, A-Z, a-z... more precisely, in utf-8 byte order).

Comment: So, there is no way to do it?

Comment: Identify the objects you want, using `aws s3api list-objects`, then sync them explicitly.